# Adding a top progress navigation bar in beamer

Tags: beamer, mini-frames

I want to add a top progress navigation bar to my presentation but I'm unable to figure out how. I searched google, all I was able to find were questions on how to remove that.

This is an example of what I want exactly: 
[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt, xcolor=x11names]{beamer}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\mode<beamer>{\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{fg=blue, bg=black!20}
```

Edit:

I just found that I should use this:

```
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
```

However the bullets of the subsections appear in a vertical way (not horizontal as in the pic above) which is sooo ugly. How to solve this?!

Comment: You should really think about the community when you ask a question. Post a sample presentation that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and replicate your results. Would you be able to do this so we don't have to create what seems like a 25-slide presentation before we can get working on a solution?

Answer (score 9):

This kind of navigation can be added with `\useoutertheme{miniframes}`. In its default configuration the bullets are below each other, to get them in a row, use `\documentclass[compress]{beamer}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt, xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\mode<beamer>{\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{fg=blue, bg=black!20}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}

    \begin{document}    
        \section{Section1}
        \subsection{Subsection1}
        \begin{frame}
            \frametitle{Frame11}
        \end{frame}

        \subsection{Subsection2}
        \begin{frame}
            \frametitle{Frame12}
        \end{frame}

        \section{Section2}
        \begin{frame}
            \frametitle{Frame2}
        \end{frame}

        \subsection{Subsection1}
        \begin{frame}
            \frametitle{Frame21}
        \end{frame}

        \subsection{Subsection2}
        \begin{frame}
            \frametitle{Frame22}
        \end{frame}

        \subsection{Subsection3}
        \begin{frame}
            \frametitle{Frame23}
        \end{frame}

        \section{Section3}
        \begin{frame}
            \frametitle{Frame3}
        \end{frame}

        \frame{}

    \end{document}
```